# Correct way to use DetachableResultReceiver

Tags: android

Google uses it in their [Google I/O](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/DetachableResultReceiver.java) app, but there is little to no documentation on how to use it. What's the correct way?